# Can I make an LED turn OFF when current ON, and ON when current OFF?

Tags: transistors, led, light

Im an electronics noob so this may be a stupid question....but here's some context to my problem.

I am rebuilding a motorcycle and have swapped out the dash. There is a wire coming off the bike to illuminate a 'Neutral' light. Im pretty certain I have the right wire however whenever the bike is in neutral, the light extinguishes. Whenever the bike is in gear, the light illuminates. This is backwards. I need the light to come on when the bike is in neutral.

Being a motorcycle, the system is 12V (i think?). I have rigged up all the other lights (backlights, indicators, high-beam) and all works well.

So, first question... Does it make sense the circuit be rigged up this way? I have swapped a more modern digital dashboard for an analogue one if this is a factor.

Second question... Can i inverse this to make the light do the opposite?

Comment: The wire that goes into the gearbox will connect to an internal gearbox switch - you need to show how that switch fully connects to your system, I suspect that connecting one side of your lamp to 12 volts might fix the issue but, without clear wiring information you should not try it.

Comment: Google seems unable to provide me a wiring diagram, the manual doesn't include one and i'm certainly not savvy enough to build one. 

Through process of elimination of the wires running into the dash I worked out which one was for neutral. Playing with the gear selector got it operating.

Do you mind elaborating on "connecting one side of your lamp to 12 volts might fix the issue"? I don't quite understand what you mean. By lamp, do you mean headlight?

Thanks for the response btw.

Comment: Without wiring details, no.

Comment: If you have the space, you could have that wire drive a relay which has a normally closed contact.  This would invert the signal.

Comment: So it is possible to invert the signal then. Good to know. Plenty of space to hide some extra wiring. 

I'll see if the local electrical store (Jaycar) can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it’s like most motorcycles, the neutral switch has a single pin that connects to engine case ground (closes) when the selector is in neutral. It’s open otherwise. You can check this with an ohmmeter.

Some motorcycles might use a 2-pin connector if the engine is in an anti-vibration mount (e.g., a newer Harley), but nevertheless would connect to ground via the harness when closed.

Normally the neutral lamp has one side connected to the switch and the other to the +12 from ignition. So current flows from 12V, though the lamp, then through the closed neutral switch to ground. If your dash has the lamp connected to the ignition switch then that’s almost you need to do (don’t forget to add a load resistor to the LED or you will fry it.)

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much for your response.